# Xamarin Binding for an android sdk

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I am creating a xamarin binding for an android SDK, and I get a few errors while I build the binding project. One of the error is:

Error CS0234: `The type or namespace name ITrustDefenderMobileStandardV2' does not exist in the namespaceCom.Threatmetrix.TrustDefenderMobile'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (WePayAndroidBinding)`

And when i double click the error it shows the following code:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.threatmetrix.TrustDefenderMobile']/class[@name='TrustDefenderMobile']"
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/threatmetrix/TrustDefenderMobile/TrustDefenderMobile", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
public partial class TrustDefenderMobile : global::Java.Lang.Object, global::Com.Threatmetrix.TrustDefenderMobile.ITrustDefenderMobileStandardV2 {
```

It would be really great if someone can help to resolve this error. If more information is needed, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working. I added the following statement in the Metadata.xml file.

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.threatmetrix.TrustDefenderMobile']/interface[@name='TrustDefenderMobileStandardV2']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

I had decompiled the jar files, and helped me. Please refer this blog for any further help. http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/98568/Xamarin-Mobile-Development-Consuming-Java-Libraries-from-C-in-Xamarin-Android-Part-2